# pip install cryptography fails with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1 on MacOS

Tags: python, pip, cryptography, failed-installation

Spent almost more than an hour looking for a solution on how  to successfully install `cryptography` on MacOS High Sierra v10.13.3

By using this command under a virtual environment.

```
$ pip install cryptography==0.9
```

I get this lengthy set of errors:

```
src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_e7d09016xc302a38b.c:505:6: error: conflicting types for 'BIO_new_mem_buf'
BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(void *, int);
     ^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/bio.h:692:6: note: previous declaration is here
BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(const void *buf, int len);
     ^
src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_e7d09016xc302a38b.c:2019:15: error: redefinition of 'SSLv2_method' as different kind of symbol
SSL_METHOD* (*SSLv2_method)(void) = NULL;
              ^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h:2349:19: note: previous definition is here
const SSL_METHOD *SSLv2_method(void); /* SSLv2 */
                  ^
src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_e7d09016xc302a38b.c:2020:15: error: redefinition of 'SSLv2_client_method' as different kind of symbol
SSL_METHOD* (*SSLv2_client_method)(void) = NULL;
              ^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h:2351:19: note: previous definition is here
const SSL_METHOD *SSLv2_client_method(void); /* SSLv2 */
                  ^
src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_e7d09016xc302a38b.c:2021:15: error: redefinition of 'SSLv2_server_method' as different kind of symbol
SSL_METHOD* (*SSLv2_server_method)(void) = NULL;
              ^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h:2350:19: note: previous definition is here
const SSL_METHOD *SSLv2_server_method(void); /* SSLv2 */
                  ^
src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_e7d09016xc302a38b.c:17971:29: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  { result = BIO_set_fd(x0, x1, x2); }
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/bio.h:520:64: note: expanded from macro 'BIO_set_fd'
# define BIO_set_fd(b,fd,c)      BIO_int_ctrl(b,BIO_C_SET_FD,c,fd)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~                  ^~
src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_e7d09016xc302a38b.c:45897:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  { result = X509_CRL_get_version(x0); }
           ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/x509.h:602:42: note: expanded from macro 'X509_CRL_get_version'
# define         X509_CRL_get_version(x) ASN1_INTEGER_get((x)->crl->version)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings and 4 errors generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

And I also tried the following instruction on this GitHub [source](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2692#issuecomment-272773481) by using brew, giving the command `brew install openssl`, then make changes on `~/.bash_profile`.

Unfortunately the error is persistent and I still get this

```
2 warnings and 4 errors generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

At the end of the terminal console.

Comment: It appears the version of openssl expected by cryptorgraphy and the version of openssl you have installed are different.  Have you explored that?

Comment: If you really need to install `cryptography` _that_ old (versions older than 1.2 are unsupported for a long time now and surely have unpatched security issues), then you need an older version of OpenSSL, including old headers. Install (or build from source) the OpenSSL 0.9.8, then reinstall `cryptography`, linking to the old lib if necessary.

Comment: @hoefling seems like that is the issue and yes our dependencies is old since our system was built 3 years ago and still on progress. Upgrading cryptography version in  this case seem the right solution but downgrading openssl version if i decided to use the older crypto would be fine also. Thanks I'll write an update to this post. awesome guys